# JavaFx cast to Object for a varargs call

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Following code i meet an error like this how can i solve this.

: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
                ListView.getItems().addAll(ad);
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

```
String []ad = new String[100];
String []bd = new String[100];
String []cd = new String[100];



        int i=0;
try {
        Class.forName(m_Driver2);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    String query2 = "";

    try {
        //Create connection object
        m_Connection2 = DriverManager.getConnection(m_Url2, "root", "");

        //Create Statement object
        m_Statement2 = m_Connection2.createStatement();
        query2 = "SELECT * FROM diziler";

        //Execute the query
        m_ResultSet2 = m_Statement2.executeQuery(query2);
        System.out.println("TTTTTTTTTTT");
        while (m_ResultSet2.next()) {

            //System.out.print(m_ResultSet.getString(1));
            //cBox.getItems().addAll(m_ResultSet.getString(1));
             ad[i]=m_ResultSet2.getString(1);
             bd[i]=m_ResultSet2.getString(2);

             //files=m_ResultSet.getString(3);
             //File f4 = new File(files);


            i++;
            System.out.print(", ");
            System.out.print(m_ResultSet2.getString(1));
            System.out.print(", ");
            System.out.print(m_ResultSet2.getString(2));
            System.out.print("\n"); //new line

        }
            ListView.getItems().addAll(ad);


    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(query2);
    }
    finally {

        try {
            if (m_ResultSet2 != null)
                m_ResultSet2.close();
            if (m_Statement2 != null)
                m_Statement2.close();
            if (m_Connection2 != null)
                m_Connection2.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution*

Specify the ListView type when you define the ListView.

```
ListView<String> listview = new ListView<>();
```

*Explanation*

If you don't tell the ListView that it is for a list of strings, then when you try to add your array to the listView via the [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addAll%28E...%29) method, the Java compiler warns that it can't work out if you are trying to add the individual items in the array to the backing list as different items in the list or the array itself as just a single item in the list.  But when you tell the ListView that it is a list of strings, the compiler is smart enough to know that you couldn't possibly be wanting to add the array of lists as a single item in the list, but instead want to add each individual item in the array to the list.  Additionally, when you specify the type of the ListView, stronger type checks are available and it is no longer possible to add something of an incorrect type to the list by mistake.

*Sample Code*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListLoader extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
   }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String[] data = { "apple", "orange", "pear" };

        ListView<String> listview = new ListView<>();
        listview.getItems().addAll(data);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(listview));
        stage.show();
   }
}
```

*Unrelated Advice*

A couple of incidental comments on your code:

1. Use Java naming conventions (don't call a variable ListView, instead call it listView).
2. Do your long running tasks (like database queries) in another thread and use JavaFX concurrency utilities to ensure that your ListView items aren't updated on that thread.  See this [example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4957967) of populating a ListView from a database using Tasks.
3. Use consistent indenting.
4. Remove useless and irrelevant code and comments before posting (or better yet, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org)).
5. When posting a JavaFX question, use the javafx or javafx-2 tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice. i am beginner programmer sorry about my mistakes.

Comment: Don't worry, this part of [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) is weird and confusing.  I had to write a little program just to work out what was wrong and how to fix it and I have been using Java for a long time.